# Some Enterprise Library dependencies are not copied to the main project

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library, .net-4.6.1

I have a project (FWIW, it's a WCS project), let's call it `WcfProj`. `WcfProj` references another project, let' call this `ClassLib`. `ClassLib` references few Enterprise Library DLLs; e.g., `Common`, `Data`, `ExceptionHandling`, `ExceptionHandling.Logging`, and `Logging`.

Note that `WcfProj` does not directly reference any Enterprise Library DLL.

When I compile or publish `WcfProj`, I get all the DLLs referenced by `WcfProj` and the ones referenced by `ClassLib`, except `ExceptionHandling.Logging`.

Does anyone have an idea about why is this?

P.S., both `WcfProj` and `ClassLib` are .NET v6.4.1 projects. Enterprise Library, on the other hand, is an very old version that is compiled from source to target .NET v3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check CopyToLocal for the Dll . Should be true.
2. Also if you are not using any classes from ExceptionHandling.Logging in Classlib. then it does not get copied over.

Comment: (1) the Copy Local is already set to True for all libraries in `ClassLib`, (2) You are right, `ExceptionHandling.Logging` is not used in `ClassLib` and this is why it was not copied.